# ASP .Net Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a form to populate a gridview with x users. However I want whenever I call the function if there is only 1 user displayed inside the gridview to autoselect that first user.

So within my callback function I have

```
if (users.count == 1)
{
   // Do something
}
```

I currently use the following function upon someone pushing "select" alongside the gridview.

```
Users_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

It would be nice if I could reuse this function and do something like

```
if (users.count == 1)
{ 
Users_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e); 
}
```

Comment: you can, just call that method. Otherwise extract its contents into another method they both call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`GridView.SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex.aspx) property.

Setting this property to `0` after binding the data and checking for at least one item ought to do the trick. Technically you could call the event handler method, but to no end other than executing your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the GridView's OnLoad method and call your function there. Data has been bound when the OnLoad method is called.

```
public void GridView_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Assuming one row means 1 user and gv is your gridview object
     if (gv.Rows.Count == 1) //(user.count == 1)
     {
           //call your selected function here
     }
}
```

Comment: my problem is once I know only one row is returned I now want to autoselect the first row. I don't know how to autoselect that first row and use that users information for further manipulation